# How do I rotate the camera instead of the world?

Tags: opengl, math, camera, quaternions

I am using OpenGL to create a graphics engine. However, when I apply rotations to rotate my camera in place, the world turns instead.

See here (please excuse some clipping issues - the remnant cubes don't exist):

[image]

I use quaternions to rotate my camera which has an initial rotation. Every time the user hits `Q` or `E`, I multiply the original quaternion with a rotation around the Y-axis.

The following is my camera to clip matrix, based on the camera's quaternions:

```
1 - 2y^2 - 2z^2    2xy - 2wz    2xz + 2wy    0
2xy + 2wz    1 - 2x^2 - 2x^2    2yz - 2wx    0
2xz - 2wy    2yz + 2wx    1 - 2x^2 - 2^2     0
-xt    -yt    zt    0
```

where `x/y/zt` are the camera's current position, and `w,x,y,z` are the camera's current quaternion rotation vector.

My matrices are multiplied as such:

```
cameraToClip * worldToCamera * modelToWorld * position
```

where `position` is the location of the vertex being transformed.

Should I be multiplying every vertex by the camera matrix? How do I debug this issue further?

Comment: It would be appear I've fixed this by multiplying by the inverse `worldToCamera` matrix. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: Yes, this would be the solution. Since what you actually need to do is transform the world to the view, i.e. perform exactly the opposite transformation of transforming the camera to the world.

Comment: The secret to understanding the camera in OpenGL is that there is no camera :)  Hence the "weird" approach of rotating the world the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I simply had to call `inverse` on my `worldToCamera` matrix. This is because, as datenwolf states, I'm transforming in the opposite direction.